# Plot x and y datapoints in Visual C++

Tags: c++, graph, gnuplot

I am new to plotting graphs in Visual C++. I want to use arrays as input for x- and y-axis coordinates. Please suggest some way of doing so. I have read the previous posts but I am finding gnuplot++ complex for plotting graphs.

Comment: I don't think VS is an integral part to this question. You might try to turn this into a "library search" question to avoid it being closed.

Comment: If you are already using qt, [qwt](http://qwt.sourceforge.net/) works very nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these out:

http://koolplot.codecutter.org/ >> its only 2d plotting but might help you as you want an easy one.

http://mathgl.sourceforge.net/mathgl_en/mathgl_en_7.html >> mathgl, if your'e familiar with opengl, this becomes easy for you to use

www.astro.caltech.edu/~tjp/pgplot >> fortan c-callable graph plotter (please bear with me as stack overflow is preventing me from posting more than two hyperlinks)

if you have a lot of data, i mean seriously large then it might be worth trying to learn opengl as you'll be direcly dealing with raster graphics.

one advantage is that you can set the viewport(how many pixels and how big) in common words you can deal with 100000*100000 points in your calculations but display it in a window of 500*500 pixels as a reduced image.

google opengl you'll go to the website, i believe edward angel's books are really good to learn and teach you only what you need.